# HTML background with overlapping text that is part of document flow

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple HTML document that has two main divs - the first one has a background image w/a background size of cover so that the image takes up the entire top portion of the screen, the second div is directly beneath the first div and contains an img tag.

This seems simple enough, but when I apply a background:url style to my first div, scrolling down causes my second div image to overlap the background image of the first div. I expected this so I set a height property in my first div and this has no effect.

How do I make the first image cover the first div but not have the second one overlap it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title></title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'lato'; font-size:18px;">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div style="background:url('http://www.screensavergift.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/BeautifulLakeView1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size:cover; height:1100px" class="row">

            <div class="row">
                <div style="margin-top:20px" class="text-right col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                    Login | Sign Up
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div style="background-color:rgba(62,83,78,0.2); margin-top:10px" class="text-center col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                    <span style="color:white; font-size:40px;">
                        Join us in God's country!
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="http://www.ynaija.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Bird.jpg" alt="Cyrillic alphabet" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

See an example of what I'm trying to do here:

http://jsfiddle.net/y0oL6k4d/

Comment: Looks fine in jsfiddle, what is your issue?

Comment: I don't want the bird to overlap the background image in the first div. I want the document to flow as if two imgs were stacked vertically on top of each other.

Comment: https://stacksocial.com/ ... like what you see here; notice how the background image is part of the document flow.

Comment: you used background-position:fixed , behavior is normal , remove it or set scroll maybe ?

Comment: Thank you GCyrillus. So simple. I removed fixed and it work as I want it to. Thank you.